# libvlc - python access violation reading 0x00000094

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Buenas tardes estoy tratando de generar un reproductor en Python con PyQt usando el binding de Python para VLC (libvlc), pero me lanza el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
import vlc
import time

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.player = self.instance.media_player_new()
        self.media = self.instance.media_player_new('C:/Users/Angel/Videos/TT T01-08/TT T01-12.mkv')

        self.player.set_media(self.media)

        self.player.play()
        self.time.sleep(50)

app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema principal es que estás usando el método equivocado para crear tu instancia de `Media`:

- `self.instance = vlc.Instance()` crea una instancia vlc base.
- `self.player = self.instance.media_player_new()` crea un reproductor vacío.
- `self.media = self.instance.media_player_new('C:/Users/.../TT T01-12.mkv')` crea **otra** instancia del reproductor, pero esta vez recibe la ruta a reproducir. en este punto podrías hacer `self.media.play()`.
- `self.player.set_media(self.media)`: esto es lo que causa el error, estás intentando pasar como medio a reproducir a un reproductor otra instancia de *Media Player*.

Debes usar el método [`vlc.Instance.media_new()`](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/) para crear `self.media`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
import vlc
import time

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.player = self.instance.media_player_new()
        self.media = self.instance.media_new('C:/Users/Angel/Videos/TT T01-08/TT T01-12.mkv')

        self.player.set_media(self.media)
        self.player.play()

app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

No se porqué usas `time.sleep` pero nunca debes usarlo en una GUI, es bloqueante por lo que la interfaz se congela y deja de responder al bloquearse su *mainloop*.

El código anterior se limita a reproducir el vídeo en una ventana externa a la de la interfaz Qt, lo normal es que quieras integrar el reproductor en tu app. Es relativamente simple embeber el reproductor en un `QFrame` por ejemplo:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import vlc

class Principal(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.resize(960, 540)

        self.instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.player = self.instance.media_player_new()

        self.video_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.player.set_hwnd(self.video_frame.winId())
        self.box_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.box_layout.addWidget(self.video_frame)
        self.widget.setLayout(self.box_layout)

        self.media = self.instance.media_new('C:/Users/Angel/Videos/TT T01-08/TT T01-12.mkv')
        self.player.set_media(self.media)
        self.player.play()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

> **Nota:** la forma de conectar el widget vía `id` con el reproductor es plataforma-dependiente. Para linux (X)  se usa el método `set_xwindow`, para Windows `set_hwnd`  y para MacOs `set_nsobject`